solve a problem connecting a Laravel project to a remote server
I have a Laravel project which, following somes operations, generates an archive and needs to place it on a remote server. To carry out my tests, I created a VM running Ubuntu server configured with an SSH connection. When connecting the project to the server to deposit the archive, I want to use dual authentication via an SSH key system and a more traditional user password method. The first phase is carried out correctly, my private key is recognised and it's during the second part that the problem occurs.
After checking, the user name entered was correct, but the only error message was this one:
"message:proposition #536 SftpAdapter.php:+232 Could not login with username: test, host: 192.168.*.**"
The user account has been configured like this to simplify the test, :
username:test
password:test
The message given above is the only log I have, it comes from the laravel logs.
On the VM side, after checking several log files theoretically exist but I only found one out of the three theoretical ones and it didn't provide me with the information I was hoping for.
So I tried to make the logs appear on the VM side but I can't find any parameter corresponding to these famous logs.
What's more, I've gone through the various elements that can cause this problem point by point, but none of them is the cause.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As my small idea. I think you should troubleshoot one of these settings:

Verifiy that the host and the port match together
make sure that your VM allows incoming SSH connections
verify the public key given to your Laravel app. That public_key is not the same as your laravel key. pay attention on it.

As i see, it looks like the remote VM does not allows your Laravel server to communicate with him. Try to log in with your terminal by using ssh test@192.168.xxx.xxxx, then provide the password test. If is works, that means your laravel .env file needs to be edited in order to change the host and the port. Or verify the ssh_public_key you provided to laravel
